# Symfony and Twig, prerender, parse view, replace content

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I need replace some content in every file of view. But content in many places is just a text, not a variable, co i cant use `variable|replace()` filter.

Is there any way to get view (eg in Controller) content before displaying so I can pass it to some function and return ready to display content?
Or maybe there is way for replace all content in `block` tag?

Comment: $this->renderView(twigname,array('text_to_replace''=>$text). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Why dont you just change your views and make it a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony controller has 2 functions `render()` and `renderView()`, the former renders a view and returns a `Response`, the latter just renders the view and returns the string result.

so you could in your action:

```
$content = $this->renderView('my-view.html.twig', [...]);

$content = str_replace('my text', 'my new text', $content);

return new Response($content);
```